# What is the Mysql query and explain how please

Tags: mysql

```
mysql_query("SELECT `value` FROM `setting` WHERE `id` = 1");
```

if someone can explain to me what this means and what the code i'd use as a query i would be very grateful.

Comment: This is in PHP, right? Here's the manual: [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). I don't understand the second part of your question: "what the code i'd use as a query" - what are you trying to query for?

Answer (score 2):

This mean you extract  the value of field "value" from the table named "setting" where the field "id" has the value 1 in this table.

Then, I don't know if this is what your want x).

Answer (score 1):

Usually most of the work done with MySQL involves pulling down data from a MySQL database. In MySQL, data is retrieved with the "SELECT" keyword. Think of SELECT as working the same way as it does on your computer. If you wanted to copy some information in a document, you would first select the desired information, then copy and paste.

```
<?php
// Selects the value field from table "settings" where the field "id" is 1.
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `value` FROM `setting` WHERE `id` = 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

// Print out the contents of the entry 
echo "Value: ".$row['value'];
?>
```